# How to "pre-select" a file in a SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog

Often times in a `SaveFileDialog` I find that the file that the user wants to save to is already selected, and all they have to do is hit enter. I would like to create this functionality in my program.

This is my current attempt:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog(); 
dlg.Filter = "CCT files (.cct)|*.cct"; //Filter only .cct extensions

Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog(); //Show the SaveFileDialog

directoryName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); //ATTEMPT to get the directory that has been opened
fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@directoryName, "*.cct"); //Put the name of the fill path to the file into string form
dlg.FileName = fileList[0]; //Set SelectedItem to the previous file
```

I think my problem is that whenever I try to `GetCurrentDirectory`, it returns the programs location (the Debug folder), and not the save location being opened up.

How do I allow a preselect of the file in the location with `.cct` as it's extension?

**Update for clarity**

I think it would clear things up to note that a `SaveFileDialog` always opens up to the last directory that you saved a file to in that program. This is the directory that I want to work with. It's like what happens when you are overwriting a file that you've been working on.

Comment: Have you tried setting the SaveFileDialog's InitialDirectory? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: what's with this line of code..? `Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog(); //Show the SaveFileDialog` why not just do something like `if(dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){}` then assign the fileName etc...

Comment: Thanks Steve I thought it was Windows sorry

Comment: I like your thought there @eddie_cat. I have tried setting the `InitialDirectory`, but in order to do that I still need the save location, which doesn't seem to exist yet.

Comment: You could put it wherever you expect your users to be saving the file, e.g. My Documents. I'm a little confused what you mean, it seems like you are trying to read users' minds? How will you know the file you want is at fileList[0]?

Comment: When you loaded the file in the first place you probably should store the full path to the original file.

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to achieve(for me). Can you clarify? Do you want to select the first file in last selected path?

Comment: @eddie_cat well, there will only ever be one .cct file in a directory, and I have to use a `string` array for that line, so that's pretty much the only reason i use `fileList[0]`. I think you're just getting confused because SaveFileDialog automatically goes to the directory where a file was last saved. It's that directory that I want.

Answer (score 2):

The key to solve your problem is to give, before opening the SaveFileDialog, a value to the `InitialDirectory` property.

Of course, the first time you call this SaveFileDialog there is no previous record of the choosen folder. So you could point this value to a well known folder like `MyDocuments`.

After the first call you could get the choosen path and save it in a predefined setting of your configuration file. Now when the call is made again you could simply retrieve this value and apply it to InitialDirectory

```
// A default folder when no previous one has been saved...
string directoryName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog(); 
dlg.Filter = "CCT files (.cct)|*.cct"; //Filter only .cct extensions

// Try to get back the previous saved folder... 
if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WorkingDirectory"] != null)
   directoryName =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WorkingDirectory"];
dlg.InitialDirectory = directoryName;

fileList = Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*.cct"); 
if(fileList.Length > 0)
{
    // Set the default name to show in the dialog
    dlg.FileName = Path.GetFileName(fileList[0]); 
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog(); 
    if(result.HasValue && result.Value)
    {
        // Try to insert or update the setting with the choosen path
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None); 
        if(config.AppSettings.Settings["WorkingDirectory"] != null)
            config.AppSettings.Settings["WorkingDirectory"].Value = Path.GetDirectoryName(dlg.FileName);
        else
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("WorkingDirectory",Path.GetDirectoryName(dlg.FileName));
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it resets `directoryName` every time, I find that `fileList.Length` is always equal to zero because no .cct files exist in MyDocuments. Therefore, a `SaveFileDialog` never opens up. Am I missing something?

Comment: It should happen only the first time, then, when you press OK the directory selected should be written in your config file. At the next run the new value should be read from the config

Comment: Yes, if you run this code more than one time without exiting the application you need the call to RefreshSection otherwise the value in cache kicks in and you don't see the change.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think that I've figured out how I want to handle this. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Er... you *do* realize that it's *your* app that's spawning the SaveFileDialog, don't you?

So each time you show the save dialog, just remember where the save file was by consulting the FileDialog.FileName property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.filedialog.initialdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx), and parse the directory path out of the file name.

You can save that in some handy location, and every time you show the save file dialog, set the initial directory based on that path.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.filedialog.initialdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

I'm not going to put any code here, because I'm of the mind that this is a design-approach issue rather than a "show-me-the-code" issue. Let me know if you need me to illustrate via code (hope not!)

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem, basically all I had to do was store the last selected file name. I decided, that since `SaveFileDialog` already opens the last visited path by default that in the first run of the program, I would allow the user to select the file that they would like to save to. Then I would store the file path, and upon save, if a file name exists, I would set the new `dlg.FileName` to the stored path.

```
string currentFileName;
string[] currentFileName_Array;

Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "CCT files (.cct)|*.cct"; //Filter only .cct extensions

if (currentFileName != "" && currentFileName != null) //If a pre-selected filename exists
    dlg.FileName = currentFileName_Array[currentFileName_Array.Count() - 1];

Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

if (result == true)
{
    currentFileName = dlg.FileName; //Save the selected File Name
    currentFileName_Array = currentFileName.Split('\\');
}
```

Thanks to everyone for your help!